# Swift Dictionary Error: EXC Bad Instruction

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am currently facing a bit of a problem regarding the use of dictionaries, and I can't really seem to solve it. Here is basically what the problem is;

I have a dictionary like so:

```
let dict : Dictionary<String, String> = ["Word1":"Word2", "Word3":""Word4"]
```

So basically this is what my Dictionary looks like, except it's way bigger with probably over 400 "Word1:Word2"-words. The thing is that when I run the code, it builds successfully - but when I run the code in the simulator I can an error of type EXC_Bad_Instruction. This suddenly occurred when it (from what it looks like) exceeded a specific number. Let's say when I try to add in "Word5:Word6". Then I get an error, but if I just keep it with Word1:Word2 and Word3:Word4, then it runs.

Could someone please help me with this, as it's really frustrating - as I've tried to look for 'nil's' in my code, but with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you copy in more of your code?

Comment: And the key word is _copy_. Do not type in something that is kind of like your code. Copy your _real code_ and _paste_ it right into your question.

Comment: Can you show the code you are running that is getting the EXC? Also, do you have a global breakpoint set so it will stop on the EXC line before it crashes? That helps narrow it down.

Comment: That's basically it. A huge dictionary with words..

Comment: @jeremynealbrown It's basically just a dictionary of many 'bad words' as I am trying to make a filter that replaces for instance 'damn' with 'd***'. It's really not much more. But it works fine running it with a good 250-300 words, but at one line it just gives me this error. It's like I can't add any more words to the dictionary.. And no I don't have any global breakpoint, as I don't know what that is.. :/

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose responded to you, regarding breakpoints as well.

Comment: @anska http://crushbeercrushcode.org/2012/11/four-tips-for-debugging-in-xcode-like-a-bro/ <- check out step 2 in this blog post to set a global exception breakpoint

Comment: also, is this word list hard coded or pulled in from another source?

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose This is coded from scratch, yes. But it's really not anything big. It's as I've said, just a huge dictionary. And thanks for the link, I will try to find out more now. I will update this.

Comment: I have now solved my problem, or at least I think I have. Xcode gives an error when the dictionary is too big. Tried with a new project now, and I created a big 500+ dictionary with similar words - and it gave me this EXC Bad Introduction error again. And I know for a fact that there is nothing wrong with the code. Could anyone else try this as well, please?

Comment: Could you please verify this, @MySpecialPurpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I was able to replicate this error was when there was a duplicate key in the dictionary. I would take a look through the list and make sure there isn't a duplicate key anywhere. Try copying the dictionary into a playground and checking it there. It'll report that error if there is a duplicate key somewhere. It won't, unfortunately, show you where the duplicate is though.

With no duplicate:
[image]

With duplicate:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me a lot!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra " 
Try this:

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, String> = ["Word1":"Word2", "Word3":"Word4"]
```

It also works without explicit type definitions:

```
let dict = ["Word1":"Word2", "Word3":"Word4"]
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice - but that's not the case either :/